# call api with httpclient angular something's wrong

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I try to simply display my json but something's wrong, I can't find my mistake, I also imported httpclientModule in app.module.ts.

the error I have in my console is

"" ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.""

**boat.json**

```
{
    "Voilier": [
        {
            "img": "/assets/img/boat-img/voilier.jpg",
            "longeur": 10,
            "largeur": 20,
            "tirantEau": 50,
            "equipage": true,
            "annexe": false
        }
    ],
}
```

**boat.service**

```
 configUrl: string = 'assets/json/boat.json';

  constructor(private htpp: HttpClient) { }

  getBoat(): Observable<IBoat[]> {
    return this.htpp.get<IBoat[]>(this.configUrl);
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
public user: IBoat[] = [];

  constructor(private boatService: BoatService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.boatService.getBoat()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.user = data
      });
  }
```

**html**

```
 <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let bott of user">
            <td>{{bott.longeur}}</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Check the request url configUrl, is it working with perfect link?

Comment: `this.user = data.Voilier` maybe?

Comment: @PalashKantiBachar if I console.log(this.configUrl); I don't have the json that is displayed in my console

Comment: Is the JSON file in your angular application? or remote server.

Comment: my JSON file is in my assets/json/boat.json

Comment: Can you share `IBoat`?

Comment: export interface IBoat {
    img: string;
    longeur: number;
    largeur: number;
    tirantEau: number;
    equipage: boolean;
    annexe: boolean;
}

Answer (score 1):

I think in the subscribe you should assign `data.Voilier` to the user property like this:

```
this.boatService.getBoat()
 .subscribe(data => {
   this.user = data.Voilier
 });
```

Comment: i have this error :  Property 'Voilier' does not exist on type 'IBoat[]'.
20         this.user = data.Voilier;